# ngrepeat not working with json data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I debug for hours and have no idea what's wrong.

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in tabs[0].tabFriends">
{{friend.name}}
</li>
```

Here is my plunker demo :

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6hBpwDBxAltt0HHWlEd?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I found and corrected (link below) when looking through your plnkr:

- you referenced script1 before angular, angular must be first

  - line 1 of script1 is calling angular.module, but angular is not defined yet because that script has not yet loaded.
- you are attempting to inject $routeParams into your controller, but have not included 
  [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) your options are:

  - remove $routeParams from the controller declaration (you're not using it)
  - add a reference to that module
- you are assigning `$scope.tabs = tabs;` before you define tabs, move that to after

  - or just combine it into one statement: `$scope.tabs = [{}, {}];`

After making those changes, it was showing data. ([plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gMLGujap2LXHWrvtwHdz?p=preview))

Comment: Great job Brocco! I found these exact same three things. In other words, I agree with him.